# Showing languages in content on magento

Tags: magento-1.9, translate

I know its simple to modify attributes, menu buttons etc into different languages but how do you change product content - titles and other fields?
Is there a suitable extension?

Answer (score 0):

You can set translated content in respective store for language. For example if you want to set product content for French language then go to your product switch to french store, uncheck checkbox in front of field to translate and put french content.

Here is screenshot for this.
http://prntscr.com/c9ppuz

Comment: thanks for this, is it possible to use an extension to automate this process at all, because we have hundreds of products and cant copy and paste the information into hundreds of products. even if we can get magento to reocgnise a text string and translate it this would be ideal.

Comment: I don't know about such extension exits or not but you can translate product data in bulk by import technique.

Comment: hi Gulshan how can you do this please?